# How to verify Google Apps email alias for non existent account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have a user who no longer works for us. The end goal is to have auto responder setup for that user, that says they no longer work for us.

I read that I first need to setup an alias for that user within another user’s account and then setup a canned response from that user’s account.

The problem is that the user's account has already been deleted, and the only way that I see to setup an alias requires verification from that email.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

An "alias" is a term related to the receiving of email. In the control panel, you will create an alias (labeled as nickname) for the account that will be receiving the email.

For example, nolongerhere@example.com becomes an alias(or nickname) for youraccount@example.com which will result in email to the deleted account of nolongerhere@example.com being delivered to the youraccount@example.com. This is creating an alias.

The next part is to setup send-as permission which is the part requiring verification *(send-as permission is not an alias -- although I can understand why you might assume that)*. When you setup send-as permission in youraccount@example.com to be able to send as nolongerhere@example.com, it will send an email verification to nolongerhere@example.com. Because you have already setup the alias, it will be delivered to youraccount@example.com

Comment: Thanks for your help, That makes perfect sense. I am also using flashpanel so I didn't realize I had to go into users instead of email tools. I would also like to set this up as a group nickname eventually but I don't see a way to enable canned responses from the group so it might not be possible. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Using a group or a nickname is the same. Both are for receiving email. You are correct that groups do not have a canned response but if you get the message into a user's inbox (via groups), you can use canned response on it. PS. If you like the answer, may I ask you to accept it? Thanks.